# It is possible write multilingual text with different scripts in Lyx for dummies?

Tags: lyx, languages

I'm noob in lyx. I like Lyx but in terms of multilingual is a pain ass for dummies .... I try so many times I need many languagues error error error..

It is possible for lyx ? similar to this link:
Pro I like lyx because I can use mode offline!

[How to write multilingual text with differents scripts in latex](https://es.overleaf.com/latex/examples/how-to-write-multilingual-text-with-different-scripts-in-latex/wfdxqhcyyjxz)

Example document:

```
% Preview source code

%% LyX 2.3.3 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\title{\selectlanguage{american}%
How\foreignlanguage{spanish}{ to write multilingual text with different
scripts in lyx for Dummies}}
\author{\selectlanguage{spanish}%
Lyx Community}
\maketitle

\section{Spanish}

Como escribir diferentes lenguajes en lyx para principiantes

\section{Chinese}

<LyX Warning: uncodable character '如'><LyX Warning: uncodable character '何'><LyX Warning: uncodable character '用'><LyX Warning: uncodable character 'l'><LyX Warning: uncodable character 'y'><LyX Warning: uncodable character 'x'><LyX Warning: uncodable character '中'><LyX Warning: uncodable character '的'><LyX Warning: uncodable character '不'><LyX Warning: uncodable character '同'><LyX Warning: uncodable character '腳'><LyX Warning: uncodable character '本'><LyX Warning: uncodable character '編'><LyX Warning: uncodable character '寫'><LyX Warning: uncodable character '多'><LyX Warning: uncodable character '語'><LyX Warning: uncodable character '言'><LyX Warning: uncodable character '文'><LyX Warning: uncodable character '本'>

\section{Hindi}

कैसे गीत में विभिन्न लिपियों के साथ बहुभाषी पाठ लिखने के लिए

\selectlanguage{spanish}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please show us what your have tried and what errors you get. It's hard to help without more information.

Comment: @siracusa [link](https://pastebin.com/Tn6XVYdt)

Comment: @siracusa can you help me, please?

Comment: What errors do you receive? Perhaps it is a font encoding problem in LyX. Does your .tex file compile if you use `pdflatex` directly? You also don't seem to include the `babel` package.

Comment: @siracusa Bro I configure the document in chinese, encoding utf 8 cjk(bkai) no problem, but when I copy and paste another laguage for example hindi, uncodable character... I select aply text hindi! but don't export to pdf! I don't know how to configure if I use more idioms and phrases .. Thank you for you help! I don't speak english very well.. I use Ubuntu 18.04 LTS LyX Version 2.3.2... I installed everythind I look on the website!... For example if a configure the document language hindi works! but I add in the document another phrases languague error! you know?

Comment: That sounds like a problem with your editor, not with the (La)TeX engine. An UTF-8 encoded file should be able to process any Unicode characters in the same document. If LyX isn't able to handle this, you should consider switching to another editor.

Comment: Thanks man! But I think I don't know how to write the correct orders in lyx for encoding languages...Because it's work chinese-english or hindi-english, but hindi-chinse error encondig.. so I don't have idea how to write correct sentece .. I aprreciate your help bro!

Comment: @siracusa 1.Class Document = Chinese CKJ
2. Documents-preferences - Fonts = use a nontex / lautex
3. Preamble text \setmainfont [Script=Devanagari]{Chandas}

here works! 

Another langueague how spanish or another I don't know hoy to do!

Comment: I modify Preambule text  \setmainfont [Script=Devanagari]{Chandas} to \newfontfamily{\devanagarifont}{Noto Serif Devanagari} and works!!! so I belive if I want to add another languague it's the same new preamble tex...

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your general question: Yes, LyX can write documents with different scripts. LyX has an "internal" (i.e., it is not released) file used for testing different languages and interactions (i.e., using multiple in the same document). The current development file is [here](https://git.lyx.org/?p=lyx.git;a=blob_plain;f=autotests/export/latex/languages/supported-languages.lyx;hb=HEAD) if curious. It has about 90 languages in the same document, with all kinds of scripts. It compiles for me (on Ubuntu with TeX Live 2021), but might need some setup (e.g., of fonts).

Comment: Interesting, but apparently it doesn’t take into account the recent (some of them not so recent) developments in `babel`.

Comment: @JavierBezos Thank you for pointing this out. It would be very helpful to have your advice on what specifically should be adapted so we could improve LyX's LaTeX export for babel. It sounds like our code is out-dated by a while. Would you mind sending an email to lyx-devel@lists.lyx.org to get a conversation started? No problem if you don't have time. I'm sure we could read the archive of release notes and figure things out, but your advice might be helpful to know if there is anything in particular we should prioritize. By the way, thank you very much for all of your work!

Answer (score 0):

New file, Document settings, language Spanish, Marcar fonts use non-TeX/ LaTeX

LaTeX preamble add:

```latex
% Config Chinese
\usepackage{xeCJK}

% Font Hindi
\newfontfamily{\devanagarifont}{Noto Serif Devanagari}
```

Works!